# uibModal não mostra os itens no ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, modal, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Estou usando `$uibModal` para mostrar uma lista de opções para o usuário, porém não está aparecendo no modal.

### Controller

```
app.controller("ConsultaFiltroController", function($scope, $http, $uibModal, $log) { 

  $scope.items = ['Em Análise', 'Pendente', 'Cancelado', 'Liberado', 'Aguardando Averbação', 'Averbado'];

$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

$scope.open = function(size, contrato) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ConsultaFiltroController',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function() {
                return $scope.items;

            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        console.log($scope.selected)

    }, function() {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
};

});

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {


$scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
};

$scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
});
```

### HTML

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Status</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                  <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        Selecionado: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro está no trecho marcado abaixo:

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ConsultaFiltroController', // Tá errado!
    size: size,
    resolve: {
        items: function() {
            return $scope.items;

        }
    }
});
```

Você está passando o próprio `controller` como referência. Você precisa passar o Controller que vai "controlar" o modal nesse campo. Nesse caso, passe `ModalInstanceCtrl`.

Exemplos:

- [CodePen - Código](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozYOAL).
- [CodePen - Full Page](http://codepen.io/wallacemaxters/full/ozYOAL/)

**Nota**: Para mim, funcionou usando o Angular *Ui Bootstrap 2.1*, junto com o *Angular 1.5*.